# Extract the max day of the month with a value (snow on ground cm) >0 (greater than 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to display the max date of a month where the snow on ground value is greater  than zero. Here is the head of the data frame.  It has every days reading for all of 2018.

This is what i have been able to get so far:

[image]

## Date with minimum snow​

```
dfsmin = df.rename(columns={'Snow on Grnd (cm)':'Snow_on_Grnd_cm'}, inplace=True)
​
dfs_minsnow_date1 = df.loc[df.groupby('Month').Snow_on_Grnd_cm.idxmin(),:]
​
dfs_minsow_date_noround = dfs_minsnow_date1[['Month', 'Day', 'Snow_on_Grnd_cm']]     
​
dfs_minsow_date = dfs_minsow_date_noround.round(1)
​
d ={1:'January',2:'February',3:'March',4:'April',5:'May',6:'June',7:'July',8:'August',9:'September',10:'October',11:'November',12:'December'}
​
dfs_minsow_date.Month = dfs_minsow_date.Month.map(d)
​
dfs_minsow_date.set_index('Month')
​
dfs_minsow_date.transpose()
```

Output

```
[![Output:][1]][1]
```

[image]

EDIT: thank you for the reputation points, pictures uploaded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have numeric series labelled `Day`, `Month` and `Snow_on_Grnd_cm`, you can first filter by snow amount, sort by day, then drop duplicates by month:

```
res = df.query('Snow_on_Grnd_cm > 0')\
        .sort_values('Day', ascending=False)\
        .drop_duplicates('Month')
```

Note if all values for a specific month are 0, then the result won't have a row for that month.

Comment: Yup this is what i was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given a fixed month, let's say, January:

```
MaxDayWithSnow = max(df['Day'][(df['Month'] == 'January') & (df['Snow_on_Grnd_cm'] > 0)])
```

Here, '&' means the AND operator.

Comment: you might change _df_ to your DataFrame variable name

Comment: Thank you for you feed back.